# DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or you need to define rowKey attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I had this exception in selecting a single row:

```
 javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or you need to define rowKey attribute
```

Here is the table:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="books" value="#{myCardBean.booksList}" var="book" selectionMode="single"
                 selection="#{myCardBean.selectedBook}" rowKey="book.id">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myCardBean.onRowSelect}"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{myCardBean.onRowUnselect}"/>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Book ID</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{book.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{book.title}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And this is `myCardBean` :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class MyCardBean implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private BookDao bookDao;
private List<Book> booksList;
private Book selectedBook;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    userCard();
}

@Transactional
public List<Book> userCard() {
    booksList = bookDao.findAllBooks();
    System.out.println("all Books size: " + booksList.size() + " books list type: " + booksList); // 3 , list of Object

    return booksList;
}

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("row selected, " + event.getObject());
}

public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
}
//getter/setter for selectedBook and bookList
```

And this is `Book` model class:

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;
//...
```

I defined `rowKey` and `Selection` and `selectionMode` in datatable

I have no idea why should i got this error?!

should `id` be `String` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: Why do you use `@Transactional` in managed beans? It strictly belongs to the service layer (where you defined `BookDao`).

Comment: @Tiny Thanks for remembering, It just for test simplifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rowkey is (again) defined wrong. It should be `#{book.id}` as can be seen in the PrimeFaces showcase. Not sure it is the only error, but I stopped reading further when I encountered this one.

Please investigate more yourself. StackOverflow is not a free training or consultancy site

Comment: And it is incorrectly assumed that these annotations `@ManagedBean`,
`@ViewScoped`, `@Component` which belong to two completely different, independent frameworks could work together. They will cause side effects later on for sure.

Comment: @Tiny: Might be, I've seen othe posts with the same statements. I never used spring though, so no experience there

Comment: Those posts are from poorly written blogs/articles/tutorials/books or any other kind of materials. I was also a victim of such materials and had been misleading for a long time in the past.

Comment: Sorry, I meant posts here on SO to not combine the two annotations (might have been from you though ;-) )